Align symbols in similar lines into columns with ESLint
How to configure ESLint Stylistic for JavaScript to ignore or even force alignment of symbols in similar lines? I want to have something like this:
const manager = bank.createUser("John", "Doe",        25);
const admin   = bank.createUser("Max",  "Mustermann", 33);

But if the line is alone it should still break on all incorrect spaces before operators and arguments:
const manager  = bank.createUser( "John", "Doe",   25);
//           ^^                  ^              ^^^

It should be similar to what "key-spacing" rule does for object declarations.

I doubt this is possible. What amounts to "similar lines" or not is rather hard to decide.

@Bergi If successive lines have same number of symbols and symbols are of the same type (in my example: keyword, variable, operator, variable, dot, property, argument ...) then align the symbols in columns.

That wouldn't work if you have something like manager = bank.createUser(population.random().getName()) and admin   = bank.createUser(profession.it.top(5).getName()). You may still want to align the createUser calls even if their arguments are very different expressions?
